# How to verify password on Unix (HPUX)

Tags: c, unix

I'm writing a user daemon and when the user logs on, I want to make sure that the user is the one who started the daemon. Reason is, that I need some way of running commands which can take a lot of time. Using nohup for this has some drawbacks, like I can not interact with the process anymore, so the daemon should watch these processes and allow me to interact with them.

The problem now is, how can I verify the password, as the user will not have permission to read the shadowfile and the /etc/passwd passwort is not set.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the PAM to check the user / passwd. It's also present in Unix systems. You should check the interfaces which are implemented in HPUX.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pam/

Answer (score -2):

Im not sure on how to do daemons, but I do know that in C, all you would have to do is, create a string and check whether or not that is what the user types in.

have it accept what the user sets:

```
 // accept
 printf("1. login \n 2. create information ");
```

this gives them the option, then switch the options, case 1 being the information for logging in, and then case 2 being the option that allows them to type in the information, and you saving it in something to be read later, and determining if it already created or not.

Hope this helps!